# Why Int16Array to ArrayBuffer convert back Int16Array, result is different?

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer

I have an array of data (split from a buffer) `Int16Array[326784]` with values like `[579, 578, 576, 574, 570, ...]`.

When I run `b = new Int16Array(a.buffer, 0, a.length)` the result is `Int16Array[326784]` but the values are different: `[0, 0, ..., 0, 18756, 19779, 2, 0, 19541, 4, ...]`

If I repeat the conversion: `c = new Int16Array(b.buffer, 0, b.length)` the result is same as `b`.

Why is the first conversion different?

Comment: You're doing it right. It needs more research.

Comment: I have solve this problem, and will update the answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It caused by misunderstand TypedArray.

In the question, `a = Int16Array(bufferA, x, y);`, a is only a view of buffer, the `a.buffer` is `bufferA`.

So `b = new Int16Array(a.buffer, 0, a.length)` is equal `b = new Int16Array(bufferA, 0, a.length)`